# Database for Unity3D Game (C#)

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine, persistence

I'm developing a casual crossword game using Unity3D and a C# backend.
My game downloads and parses many .json files containing the puzzles.

Currently, the .json contents (among other game status and user preferences) are stored in plain .txt files (using `System.IO` APIs such as `File.WriteAllText ()`, etc, among others). However, after a long period of usage, my app is creating thousand of .txt files in the user's devices.

I'd like to use a more solid/reliable approach, and migrate that data to a database (e.g.: `sqlite`.). I don't want to write SQL statements, instead, I'd like to use a 'high level' API that is closer to C# classes.

Does anyone know what are the current solutions to persisting data in a Unity (C#) game? I don't bother paying for a proprietary solution of that is the best one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov I already used https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net in past projects with Xamarin. I'm looking for expert opinions from Unity3D game developers.

Comment: Even though the question is old, I stumbled upon it so maybe someone else will too: They had a blog post not too long ago about this: https://blog.unity.com/technology/persistent-data-how-to-save-your-game-states-and-settings - it depends on what you need. PlayerPrefs are the easiest way (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gM73B5PyGh8 for help), JSON, binary files or bigger solutions like SQL and Realm (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jo_S02HLkI for example). Choose your poison! :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something similar to object relational mapping when you say you wish for something similar to C# classes? Thus allowing you to map class attributes directly to your database table columns?

If so C# has a library called NHibernate for achieving that. I apologize if this isn't what you meant.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

(This should be a comment but I don't have 50 rep!)

Comment: Yes, I'm familiarized with the ORM concept, I'm just asking the community what framework the developers are currently using. I used github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net in past projects with Xamarin, but not sure it's the most common used among Unity developers.